# Do AF-S DX lenses mount on Nikon D3300

Tags: lens, lens-mount

My camera currently has an AF-P NIKKOR  lens.

Comment: Have you checked your camera's manual, or the Nikon web site? I ask because there is a very clear "compatible lenses" section on Nikon's page for this camera. Or is there something deeper which is causing confusion?

Comment: Except that the AF-P lenses are newer than the manual, even for D3300, and so are not mentioned yet in the manuals. (AF-S are mentioned). The new  AF-P do have a focus motor in the lens like AF-S, except they are a quieter stepping motor instead of the "silent" motor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the D3300 can auto focus with either the AF-S or newer AF-P lenses.  Both have focusing motors in the lens.

Note that the old Nikkor P lenses are NOT at all the same as new AF-P lenses.